# How do I include references (import XY) in a java class file?

Tags: java, eclipse, oracle

I'm very new to java, actually just started using it today because we're developing for an Oracle database and we need to let it run java code.

I've been adding a simple project, like this, without problems:

```java
public class Test
{
  public static string Result()
  {
    return "Test successful!";
  }
}
```

I can load this into the database and access it with PL/SQL.
However, when I upload the class I actually need it is marked as "INVALID" in Oracle.
I think this is because of missing references in java, for example, i have these imports:

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
```

I think the problem is that my Oracle database is missing the required DLLs (actually the java equivalent for that).

Now, is there any way for me to compile my java class and include all the references I have stated in my class definition?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: If you're working with an oracle (or any other) database, you must load the database driver somewhere in your code. Take a look to [The Java Tutorials: JDBC database access](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/index.html) for an introduction.

Comment: Im not familiar with your use case in oracle, but you can always compile and package a java application/api to a jar, packaging the dependencies along with it, but those imports you've posted should come with the standard JRE... so unless you are using third party API's I dont see a jar being especially useful, and suspect its invalid for other reasons.

Comment: The code itself doesn't interact with the database, it's actually just like this:  public static String ReturnSchema(String[] TopicTypes, String[] TopicStati, String[] TopicLabel, String[] SnippetTypes, String[] Priorities, String[] UserIDs)
 {...}

I will definitely look at that Tutorial, thank you for posting. But I don't think it's that, because the method works when I remove all the "import" statements (and change the code accordingly).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All Java compilers put the import statements into the .class file. There is nothing you need to do for this. But they don't include the classes which are imported. So it's your responsibility to make sure the Oracle DB server can access any custom classes.

The Oracle database server comes with a standard Java VM, so all types below `java.*` should be visible when you upload Java code to be executed on the server.

Other types may be missing. Read the documentation, there should be an explanation how to upload a JAR archive with all the classes that you need. Then create such a JAR and upload it (instead of uploading just a single class file).

Answer (score 0):

I think Aaron Digullas answer was the closest one, it looks like the Database already has access to the standard java classes.

Actually, I'm sorry, I think I have made a mistake with importing java.

I can access the Database with SQL Developer and directly enter my source code there to insert a new java class in my database, everything works then.

It looks like I have either made an error when compiling the class or when using the "loadjava" command to insert the java class in the database.